# How can I copy or print errors from the console?

Tags: scripting, add-on, command-line

I am testing an importer addon that still has bugs. Sometimes when I import a file, I get a large error all over my screen (and in the console.) I want to save this error log out to a text file so that I can send it to the addon maker to troubleshoot. How do I do this?

Comment: Probably easiest to start Blender from a terminal/command line and redirect all output to a file. If you're on windows, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file

Comment: That's a nice idea, but might be too complex to setup for a *Tester* (IMO). I'd suggest ask the developer for implementing a debug system. Otherwise you can still copy the errors from the *Terminal* output **with ease** by selecting the lines and right-click to copy, which should work on linux, windows and osx.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the jargon, so can you tell me what the Terminal refers to? I see other people posting up their errors from blender for various things all the time, and I know they didn't go to any great lengths to get them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 2.77 there is a new built-in 'Reports to Text Block' operator, which basically copies all entries of the [Report Console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/introduction.html#report-console) into a newly created *text block* per execution:

[image]

---

However, saving errors to a text file automatically is might be too complex for a *tester* to setup (IMO). I'd suggest ask the developer for implementing a debug system. *Otherwise you can copy errors and warnings from the terminal output with ease by [running Blender via command line](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/command_line.html).*

## Linux

#### 1. Run Blender via Command Line

Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), navigate to the directory where Blender is installed, and run Blender.

```
cd <blender installation directory>
./blender
```

This will run Blender with the *Terminal* window:

[image]

Depending on your Window Manager *(Gnome, Unity, KDE etc.)* you can edit your *Launcher* or *Starter* to open up Blender with the command line automatically by setting the 'Terminal flag' to true:

**blender.desktop** (Ubuntu, Unity)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
Exec=/opt/blender-2.77a/blender %F
Icon=/opt/blender-2.77a/icons/scalable/apps/blender.svg
MimeType=application/x-blender
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
Type=Application
...
```

#### 2. Copy the Output, Errors or Warnings

Switch to the *Terminal*, select the text, then <kbd>RMB</kbd> and select 'Copy':

[image]

**Alternatively** you can also redirect the output to a text file when using the command line:

```
./<blender installation directory>/blender &> ~/mylogfile.txt
```

### Windows

#### 1. Run Blender via Command Prompt

Open the *Command Prompt* (*click Start* or hit <kbd>Win</kbd> on the keyboard and then type `cmd`), navigate to the directory where Blender is installed, and then run Blender:

```
cd c:\<blender installation directory>
blender.exe
```

This will run Blender with the *Terminal* window:

[image]

You can create a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), this opens up Blender via *Command Prompt* automatically:

> A batch file is a kind of script file in DOS, OS/2 and Windows. It consists of a series of commands to be executed by the command line interpreter, stored in a plain text file

**blender.bat**

```
"c:\<blender installation directory>\blender.exe"
```

[image]

#### 2. Copy the Output, Errors or Warnings

Switch to the *Command Prompt*. <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Mark* to enable text selection, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy:

[image]

**Alternatively** you can  you can also redirect the output to a text file when using the command line:

```
c:\<blender installation directory>\blender.exe > %homepath%\mylogfile.txt
```

---

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface
- https://www.codecademy.com/articles/command-line-commands