# New PC - Blender keeps crashing when rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I've seen people on YouTube and other social platforms designing great environments and highly detailed 3D-artwork with Blender, so I brought this new computer with pretty high specs, so that I could practice longer animations in larger worlds, but as soon as I have one single character and one single house as my entire scene, Blender crashes when I try to render (both as animation and/or single frames).
What am I missing? Ain't my hardware powerful enough?

I have the following hardware in my PC:

-

Motherboard: Asus - STRIX Z270-E GAMING ATX LGA1151

GPU: Asus - GeForce GTX 1080 8 GB ROG STRIX

CPU: Intel - Core i7-7700K 4.2 GHz Quad-Core

Memory: Kingston - FURY 32 GB DDR4-2400 (4 x 8 GB)

Comment: Start blender from cmd with a debug flag, add that and what you have done so far  to your question please

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58060/245 to get log files